# Cannot Install Libc6

Tags: linux, installation, debian, apt-get, steam

I am facing a bit of a dilemma in my attempt to install Steam on my newly Crunchbang laptop.

I downloaded the steam installer .deb, but it required libc6 2.15 or greater to install. Assuming this was no problem I searched it in Synaptic Package Manager, and although the latest version was 2.13, I installed it anyway, trying my luck. Of course, it didn't work.

So I found and downloaded a .deb install of libc6 2.19, but when I attempt to install it with Gdebi Package Installer, the "Install Package" is greyed out and unclickable. Not sure why.

What exactly should I do? It won't let me install it for whatever reason, and I can't remove libc6 and install the new version for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steam on crunchbang is tricky because of dependency issues which you have found yourself. However the community has come up with a few solutions and many seem to be happy with [this project](https://github.com/GhostSquad57/Steam-Installer-for-Wheezy), download and install the deb from the git and you should be good to go! any problems post below.